# loop and get all TextInput value in a component/screen

Tags: react-native

I know that the practice of react native is to use `onChangeText` for change value as follow.

```
<TextInput 
  onChangeText = {(text)=> this.setState({myText: text})}
  value = {this.state.myText}
/>
```

However, I wonder if i could do something like this. To summarise, I want to loop through all the `TextInput` and get the `ref` and `value`. I just want to do things in `javascript way` as follow. Is that possible to be done?

```
    <TextInput id="id1" ref={ref => (this.remark = ref)} />
    <TextInput id="id2" ref={ref => (this.remark1 = ref)} />

onSubmit = () => {
        forEach(TextInput in component) {
           console.log(TextInput.id) <- note id is custom property
           console.log(TextInput.refName)
           console.log(TextInput.value)
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal supposed to be? I mean, if you have an objective in mind please state that so we can provide a more suitable way as this doesn't seems very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I wouldn't recommend this approach. You could simply create an array of `ref`s and loop through it in your `onSubmit` function.

Answer (score 0):

> forEach(TextInput in component) {

This is not possible in any javascript environment (not only because [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax is different but also you can't expect to be able to loop over component elements by type (?) and get them)

What you want to do is not javascript way but old style browser way:

1. there are no `id`s in react-native
2. technically you could get uncontrolled TextInput's value like you would do in plain react in browser environment (via `this.textInputRef._lastNativeText`) but it's discouraged in react-native, most likely because because instead of DOM react native has to render to native views which all differ depending on the platform (iOS, Android, Windows, etc) but have to work the same

So it's not only impossible in react native but in plain react as well. It looks to me like you want to create a form, and sooner or later you will find out that you want validation or transformation on your inputs and switch back to controlled components anyway